# How to click and hold using the webdriverio

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am trying to figure out how to click and hold using webdriverio. In selenium it is like this:

```
WebElement elementToInteractWith = driver.findElement(By.id("myElement"));

Actions holdClick = new Actions(driver);

holdClick.clickAndHold(elementToInteractWith).perform();

//wait for however long you need to hold

holdClick.release().perform();
```

However i am not sure how to do that in webdriver io but cannot find anything on the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can try this.

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/jsonwp.html#buttondown

You can have a pause after this for the time you need to and then buttonup should follow.

Cheers!

Comment: sorry but how can this work? I am trying to press left click and hold until 5-7 seconds. not drag and drop

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with buttonDown on w3school page.

```
browser.url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp");
browser.buttonDown("//button[text()='Default Button']");
browser.pause(5000);
browser.buttonUp("//button[text()='Default Button']");
```

However, this is for webdriverio v4.  It says this is deprecated soon, but maybe V5 has the same api.

Comment: sorry but it says provide number instead of strong

Answer (score 0):

nothing seems to work above but i tried this in the end and it worked:

```
browser.$('//div[@data-test="touch-area"]').moveTo(0,0)
browser.buttonDown(0);
browser.pause(3000)
```